# Integration through power series

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series

Use series to estimate the value of the following function correct to $2$ decimal places:
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^4}\mathrm dx.$$  I tried to express the function as a maclaurin series but I do not know how to find its $n$ term hence could not proceed from there.

Comment: What about using Mclaurin series for $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/2}$ and then replacing $x^4$ instead of $x$? $$f(x)=(1+x)^{1/2}\Longrightarrow f(x)=1+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2+\frac{1}{16}x^3-\frac{5}{128}x^4+\ldots$$

Comment: Yup i did that. Im stuck at the part in which i have to find the n term at the numerator. I got the above function but have difficulty expressing that as a power series.

Comment: For $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/2}$ we have $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-1/2}$$ $$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}(1+x)^{-3/2}$$ And for $k\ge 3$ $$f^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2k-3)}{2^k}(1+x)^{-(2k-1)/2}$$ So, $n$-th term in the Mclaurin series is $$(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-3)}{2^nn!}$$

Comment: @MarioG: Your last formula can be simplified further since $(1)(3)(5)\cdots(2n-3) = \frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!2^{n-1}}$.

Comment: Oh yeah this is the part im actually stuck at. It is how to simplify the expression (1)(3)(5)...(2n-3) into one single term. Could u explain to me. Thanks

Comment: @yswong:yes, it seems there is no a simple form for this expression, so I think we can handle only few terms of the Mclaurin series in order to get a good estimation, what about using five terms?

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Oh yes i think that would be possible since the question only required us to find the answer correct to 2 dp. So to proceed i just integrate the above expression directly?

Comment: You need to use $ f(x) \approx  1+{\frac {1}{2}}{x}^{4}-{\frac {1}{8}}{x}^{8}$.